# Battery life of Li-Po battery if it is under constant charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo, battery-chemistry, tracking

This question is to clear my confusion because I cannot find a logical answer. Say a vehicle is installed with a vehicle tracker `(Battery specs: Li-Po 3.7V, 250mAh. Power consumption: Standby: 70mA@12V, Working: 100mA@12V)` for 2 years. The car owner took special care of his vehicle battery and there was not even a single day when his vehicle's battery went below 12 V.

This means that the internal battery of the tracker was never used because it operates on 9-32 VDC which is provided by vehicle's battery. It never discharged. It means that the tracker's battery is healthy and should be able to power it up for at least 30 minutes (as it used to be when unboxed) even after 2 years.

However, this is not the case practically. Tracker do not power up on their batteries after that much time. I was wondering how this can be proved mathematically/graphically because only then can I educate others with logic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: (Your writing was difficult for me. But I may follow. So let me put this in my words and you tell me if I understood, or not.) You have a tracker module that includes its own LiPo battery. However, the tracker should use the external vehicle battery as its power source and avoid the LiPo, so long as the vehicle battery is maintained above 9 V, which you claim it always is. So you are wondering why it might be, then, that the module would fail to operate on its LiPo should the vehicle battery should fall below the minimum 9 V while still within the 2 yr LiPo warranty. Is that about it?

Comment: @periblepsis Yes, I should have mentioned what you asked in the last sentences. The tracker has a feature that if the vehicle's battery is stolen/removed, the tracker will generate an alarm. For it to generate an alarm, the tracker must operate on its LiPo because there is no external power source now. Suppose after two years, the car's battery got stolen. The tracker should keep working on its LiPo but it does not practically. This is where I am confused. That LiPo was never used in two years. Why it is not powering up the tracker now.

Comment: Okay. I understand the question. I've no clue about why. But at least I now follow you. If the vehicle battery is stolen, but the vehicle was NOT stolen, then the question is about why the LiPo didn't do its job. One possible reason is that the LiPo is destroyed, intentionally, by those stealing the battery. If they can can steal the battery, then they can also destroy the LiPo. Or, destroy the transmission antenna. Or ? Anyway, you may need more investigative data into the instances where this failed to work.

Comment: Is it just the lighting or does that battery look swollen (i.e., end of life) to anyone else?

Comment: @AwaisSaeed - Hi, A couple of points about the cell (battery) in your photo. (a) You said in the text: "`Battery specs: Li-Po 3.7V, 250mAh`" But the cell in the photo shows a claimed rating of 80 mAh, not 250 mAh. (b) You mentioned a figure of "2 years" a couple of times, and some of the number sequences could indicate a PCB design date in 2021 and perhaps manufacturing in 2022 (i.e. 2 years ago, so that fits with what you said). *But* the battery has a manufacturing date of around 7.5 years ago, in **2016**! (And may be swollen, as Andrew mentioned.)

Comment: See added comment in my answer re battery life. || That appears to be one of these https://www.icarcomm.com/VT21-2G-Basic-Vehicle-GPS-Tracker-PG7002730 || Can you read the markings on the 8 pin IC ? | Based on the capabilities listed that is probably a custom programmed microcontroller. || Important: Is battery power applied at all times when installed? (I'd expect yes).

Comment: If that is a VT21 iCARCOMM product they MAY be willing to answer questions. Contact details [here](https://www.icarcomm.com/Content/303642.html) .

Comment: @SamGibson - The 250mAh was for another tracker, which I don't have in inventory for testing. I am using another tracker for testing. It comes with a 60mAh LiPo. That LiPo was not powering it up, so I purchased this 80mAh from local market. What numbers hinted at the PCB manufacturing date as it was correct?

Comment: @Russell McMahon - The specs and features in your link are the same for this device. I am using VG-03 GPS tracker from Jimi. Let me arrange one new VG-03 tracker, test it with a genuine LiPo and get back. And yes, tracker is always powered as long as the car's battery is attached and >9V.

Comment: @AwaisSaeed - "*The 250mAh was for another tracker {...}*" Oh :( Putting details into the question *text* which don't match the *photo*, is going to confuse people - and in this case, I wasted my time raising it. In future, if you know that there are inconsistences in the information being supplied, *please* highlight & explain them in the question. TY :) "*What numbers hinted at the PCB manufacturing date*" The "4721" (I'm guessing WWYY format) in the silk screen, below what looks like a PCB revision number ("VT21_MB_V1.3").

Comment: PLease ensure ALL text and the photos match the actual unit and battery in question. Looking at the various texts it's not 100% clear which battery meter model photo etc are what you are actually using || See my 4056 comments below . Battery age is a potentially majpr issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a long life, LiPo (and chemically identical LiIon) cells that have voltage applied to them must be managed properly to achieve a long life, even when not discharged.

- Once fully charged (typically to 4.2V) they MUST NOT be "floated" at full charge voltage. Maintaining them at 4.2V once charged will destroy them rapidly and may cause fire.  Floating at a lower voltage MAY be permissible.
- They must be charged correctly. This is usually done using a CCCV (constant current followed by constant voltage) with charge termination when charge current in CV mode reduced to a preset percentage of the CV voltage
  or
  They can be charged to some voltage to below 4.2V/cell
- Discharge voltage must not be below a preset limit.

Added after seeing photos.

- LiPo / LiIon batteries have a "calendar life" starting from when they are first used. ie Even unused they have a finite lifetime. As Sam notes, the battery shown appears to have been made in 2016. An issue is that a new unused cell may have a longer lifetime than one that has been lightly used. The factors involved are complex depending on chemical reactions in the cell. I have about 40 identical LiPo cells that are about 15 years old and have never been used. They all have a nearly identical terminal voltage of about 3.6 volts. I tried drawing significant load current from 3 of them. One worked well and two dropped to under 2 volts in a very short period. The one that did not fail would probably have operated your tracker after 15 years. The other two may have. Such longevity is unusual.

In your case the first condition applies and the second one may.
If never discharged the third one does not apply.

In your application the charge and float circuitry must be designed with battery longevity in mind.  Whether it has been depends on the capability of the designer and manufacturer. It is not possible to tell "just by looking" how well the circuit has been designed, but it is possible to make some simple measurements which give you a reasonable indication.

If the circuit maintains voltage on the cell once it is charged its life will be short.

A clear (well focused) well lit photo with good detail of the top of the circuit board would be very useful. A photo of the bottom of the PCB would also help. Brand and model details and/or a website link will help.

---

The following MAY help. The main likely problem is determining when voltage is and isn't applied to the fully charged device battery.
There are ways of doing this but they involve slight extra complexity. The following is somewhat complex and not too certain at deciding if things are being done well. It MAY help. Best would be a device circuit so we can establish good measurement points. Photos will help.

1. Obtain a new device battery.
   Measure the voltage (= V1).
2. Place the battery in the equipment and apply power.
   Measure battery voltage = Vb, with ignition on (V2a) and ignition off (v2b). These should be the same.
3. If Vb is less than 4.2V monitor voltage. This should increase towards 4.2V. Writing down voltage and time every 5 or 10 minutes may be useful but not essential.  (V3 a b c ...)
4. Once Vb reaches 4.2V (or maybe very slightly different) (time = T1) charging may continue at decreasing rate for up to 2 hours or MAY stop immediately. Try to determine when or if charging has stopped. If there is a clear time when it has call this T2.

Seek to determine if the device battery is being charged/powered. It's voltage MAY drop slightly somewhere between T1 & T2. The aim now is to determine whether voltage is still being applied.
This may not be easily done without looking at other parts of the circuit (which is where photos help).

Regardless

5. Monitor device battery voltage and disconnect car battery. Vb should start to drop. When it has dropped a VERY SMALL amount reconnect the car battery. The drop should be small enough to be clearly visible on the n=meter but no more. Say 4.2V down to 4.1V.
   Reconnect car battery. Vb ideally will NOT again increase for very small drops in Vb. If it DOES again recharge to 4.2V it suggests that the device battery is being held at 4.2V, when it should not be.

Report back.

Comment: Thanks for showing interest and providing a detailed testing guide. I have edited the question and added the details you asked.
1) Initially, Vb=3.4 V. Then I applied 13.5 V from a DC power supply (GPS-3030D). 
2) After 10 mins, Vb=4.0 V and V2a=V2b btw.
3) Then I checked after an hour and Vb=4.2 V. 
4) I disconnected 13.5 VDC and measured Vb. It instantly went to 4V. I connected the source, it instantly went to 4.2 V again. I did this 3-4 times within a minute. LiPo's voltage goes from 4.2V to 4.0V as soon as I disconnect the source. 
I think the purpose of your point # 5 cannot be met.

Comment: @AwaisSaeed  Photos may help. ||What I'm trying to ascertain is whether the charger terminates and then removes applied voltage from the cell. The sudden restoration form 4V to 4.2V is not promising. The ideal system charges to 4.2V, MAY hold charge at that voltage while battery current decreases 9due to battery chemistry) then remove voltage completely.  THEN do not recharge until Vcell falls to some lower level due to self discharge or minor load.  IF the battery is instead actively held at 4.2V it will not last anything like two years.

Comment: Hi Russell, In your recent edit, did you mean: "*The one that did not fail would probably have operated your tracker after 15 years. The other two may **not** have.*" ? My limited experience with unused Li-ion cells is like the 2 you mentioned i.e. when loaded, they very quickly drop their terminal voltage. So they *seem* OK (and give a false impression of being OK) when under zero or minimal load! But they behave as if they have developed a very high internal resistance :(

Comment: @SamGibson  I did mean MAY have BUT may and may-not are about equivalent here :-). --> Reason: The load I applied was significant and they did not fail absolutely instantaneously. I meant that in their dying gasp they MAY have done the job. BUT may-not would also apply.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - I tested on a new tracker (LiPo of 3.7V/60mAh manufactured in 2023/06/06), and the behavior is the same, just 3-4 seconds slower. The marking on the 8-pin IC is "CL4056D 3JD33V". It seems that 1) the charger always keeps a steady 4.2 V. 2) Maybe the chemistry isn't good and is speeding up the process graphically shown in this [link](https://siliconlightworks.com/li-ion-voltage) (i.e., the natural drop from 4.2 to 4.0 V). However, I am still interested in the chemistry of your sentence,"IF the battery is instead actively held at 4.2V, it will not last anything like two years."

Comment: @AwaisSaeed  The chartger IC is probably similar to and POSSIBLY identical to the [LTC4056](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/405642f.pdf) . Pages 7 to 9 are relevant and especially the timer and shutdown action on pages 8 & 9. **IF** used correctly this IC will remove charge current at the end of a timer period when Vbat is at 4.2V **AND** will automatically restart charging when Vbat falls to 4.05V.  There is SOME suggestion that a small float current may be supplied (hopefully not) but a detailed reading of the datasheet is required. A good ...

Comment: ... understanding of operation in your case could be obtained by measuring battery current at various times. A small resistor in the battery lead or an eg Hall sensor. A say 0.1 ohm resistor gives 0.1 mV/mA voltage drop - well within the capabilities of mA range on most multimeters. A 1 Ohm resistor gives better resolution but **possibly ** significant voltage drop in operation.  Once charging stops I'd hope to see a VERY small load current and no charging until; Vbat reaches 4.05V.

Answer (score 2):

The worst that happens to Li batteries in vehicles is the heat stress.

Depending on where the device is mounted, it may get as hot as 70C when in direct sunlight or 90C when the engine is running.

The combination of fully charged Li battery and high temp is especially bad.

A Li battery MAY tolerate temperatures this high if it is kept well below 50% state of charge. Pretty much possible, just charge to a lower voltage, but then you need a bigger battery for a given energy amount to be available. This also requires a precise and somewhat exotic charging control.

Small, simple and cheap devices usually have neither the mass nor volume nor bill of materials nor engineering budget to spend on luxuries like longevity.

Few customers are going to pay e.g. twice the price for a car tracker for a feature they can neither reliably test nor they are sure they need it in the first place.

Comment: Interest only: I'm currently designing a lighting and mesh radio system for use in toilets in refugee camps - many in Africa. Long battery life is a challenge.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon -- Encapsulating the enclosure in cement (still accessible by pipe) and burying it (perhaps under the outhouse) even if buried at a shallow depth, may help solve that problem.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD  A buried battery may help with temperature. Modern Lithium chemistries are reasonably OK up to 50 to 60 C charging. || I expect, and I may be wrong, that a location inside the toilet should be cooler than that almost always. "In the shade" temperatures should be usefully under 50C max. A well sealed metal box will get hotter, but sealing is not a high priority for toilets. I'm basing this only on photos that I've been supplied with. The equipment will measure and report temperature.